# How to start Hub connection on signalR with Java-client with app server based Azure signalR Service?

Tags: java, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-2, signalr-client

[image: Azure signalR service]

I have followed above signalR architecture and we have used **ASP.NET SignalR**, 
And I am trying to connect from JAVA-client,

Step 1 : IF i do negotiate request to app server than i am getting following response **strong text**

```
{
    "ProtocolVersion":"2.0",
    "RedirectUrl":"https://test.service.signalr.net/aspnetclient",
    "AccessToken":"<a typical JWT token>"
}
```

but when i am trying to connect azure signalr service from java-client than i am getting following error on `Hubconnection.start().get()`.

**

> Error:microsoft.aspnet.signalR.client.transport.NegotiationException

**
Note: **I have not used ASP.NET CORE SignalR**

**APP server is already allowed websokets,**

Can you help us to identify exact java client to connect `"ASP.NET SignalR" Azure service`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-internals#client-connections

[image]